# How to use same function to run several videos on one web page?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I have a webpage I want to put several instructional video-buttons on. I want to call same script but play the correct video depending on which button is clicked.

I have one button to play one video now. This is the code for the button:

```
 <p class="video-container">
   <div class="container text-center">               
       <button type="button" class="play-trigger btn-link " qdata-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-video" ><i class="fab fa-youtube" ></i> Watch the video</button>
   </div><!--//container-->
 </p>
```

This is the script to run the video when the button is clicked:

```
<!-- Video Modal -->
<div class="modal modal-video" id="modal-video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="videoModalLabel" class="modal-title sr-only">Video Tour</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <video width="680" height="660" controls id='pplayer'>
                    <source src="{{asset('assets/images/howto/comps.mov')}}" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div><!--//modal-body-->
        </div><!--//modal-content-->
    </div><!--//modal-dialog-->
</div><!--//modal-->
```

I want to add several more buttons. Each button will play a different video, video1, ... videox.
I would prefer to hard code the list of video names eg `var myvids = ["/mov_abc.mp4", "/mov_xyz"];` and have the script set the video name according to the button that was pressed.

Comment: Are all these _"several more buttons"_ supposed to load different files into the same `<video>` object? (or are you making video tags for multiple buttons)?

Comment: yes. the webpage is basically a how to do this and that and the next thing with text, an image and a video button which will display a different video file related to that section. So section 1 has text, image button1 to play video1, section 2 has text, image, button2 to play video2 and so on. I want to come up with one script that will handle all button presses and play the right video according to the button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you get some ideas for a working setup...

First adding several buttons like this:

```
<p class="video-container">
<div class="container text-center">             
<button type="button" id="btn_01" onClick="do_vidBtnClick( 1 )"> Watch the video #1 </button>
<button type="button" id="btn_02" onClick="do_vidBtnClick( 2 )"> Watch the video #2 </button>
<button type="button" id="btn_03" onClick="do_vidBtnClick( 3 )"> Watch the video #3 </button>
</div> <!--//container-->
</p>
```

Then add this Javascript code :

```
<script>

myVideoList = []; //# make array hold the multiple video URLs

myVideoList[0]="assets/images/howto/comps.mov";     //# add video 1 
myVideoList[1]="assets/images/howto/somefile.mp4";  //# add video 2
myVideoList[2]="assets/images/howto/nextfile.mp4";  //# add video 3

var myFileName = "";
var myPlayer = document.getElementById("pplayer");

//# Update "myFileName" using the input number set by: onClick="do_vidBtnClick( myNumForInput )" ...
function do_vidBtnClick ( inputNum )
{
    //# is "inputNum-1" since first item in array "myVideoList" is at pos zero
    myFileName = "{{asset('" + (myVideoList[ inputNum-1 ]) + "')}}";
    myPlayer.src = myFileName; 
    myPlayer.load(); myPlayer.play();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to VC.One for putting me on the right path. Here is a solution that works for me.

```
<body

<!--- video 1 code here.  button id, video id vidBtnClick all "1" -->
<p class="video-container">
<div class="container text-center">      
<button id='btn_01' type="button" onclick="do_vidBtnClick(1)">Play Video1 </button>
<video id="myvid1" width="420" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
</div><!--//container--> 
</p> 

<!--- video 2 code here. button id, video id vidBtnClick all "2"-->
<p class="video-container">
<div class="container text-center">      
<button id='btn_02' type="button" onclick="do_vidBtnClick(2)">Play Video2 </button>
<video id="myvid2" width="420" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
</div><!--//container--> 
</p> 

<!-- add as many buttons as you need. I used 7 so I have a list of 7 videos in script array ->

 <script>

    // make array for all vids, can be any names. Im using ', ' as separator
    var str='video1.mov, video2.mov, video3.mov, video4.mov, video5.mov, video6.mov, video7.mov';
    var myVideoList = str.split(', '); //split string on comma space
    //  console.log( myVideoList );
    
    function do_vidBtnClick ( inputNum )
    {
    var inum = inputNum
    var myVid=myVideoList[ inum-1 ];
    myFileName="/assets/images/howto/"+ myVid
    var myDId="myvid"+inum;
    // set up video, remove autoplay, set controls on, load
    myVideo = document.getElementById(myDId);
    myVideo.removeAttribute('autoplay');
    myVideo.src = myFileName;
    myVideo.controls = true;
    myVideo.load();
    }

</script>
       
</body>
```